# Language identifier activation events

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for microbit and I would like it to activate only for this one. I limit for the moment to python with:
`"activationEvents": [ "onLanguage:python"],`

Is it possible to create a language identifier that verify the code to see if it contains:

```
from microbit import 
or 
microbit import
```

Or is there another solution.

Thanks

Comment: I recently discovered that [VSC has a feature called LanguageDetection](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147450) (do a setting search), I can change the languageID of a file based on its content, but if a user/extension can extend the detection I have no idea. It happens from PlainText->JavaScript and the comment says it works in Markdown

Comment: but if you change the languageID to `microbit` you loose all the Python LSP functionality, you can do it yourself in the extension by analyzing the content when a file is opened or changed

Comment: Thank you for your answer so I'm going to change my approach.